# sonar issue: remove use of String(byte[])

Tags: arrays, string, sonarqube, byte

I have got a recurring sonar issue to "Remove this use of constructor "String(byte[])".
One of the example is of the code below:

```
 byte[] d = c.doFinal(e);
 return new String(d);
```

I do not know why this is popping up. Any help is welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sonar says:

> Using classes and methods that rely on the default system encoding can
>   result in code that works fine in its "home" environment. But that
>   code may break for customers who use different encodings in ways that
>   are extremely difficult to diagnose and nearly, if not completely,
>   impossible to reproduce when it's time to fix them.

you should use the `String(byte bytes[], Charset charset)` constructor instead

you can read more about it here: https://gazelle.ihe.net/sonar/coding_rules#rule_key=squid%3AS1943

Comment: Okay thanks works. But for : return new String(b.toByteArray();?

Comment: i guess it would be the same constructor if that also is a byte[].